# Close the current tab in firefox onclick of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, onclick

I have a page where a popup comes. on clicking ok button in it the current tab should close. ok button is a html input tag. I tried javascript close method in many ways and searched on net. but couldnt find solution for firefox browser alone. please help me.

Comment: Can you post the code that you are using? Or better yet, create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or [jsbin](http://jsbin.com) demo.

Comment: I have tried in always like self.close method .. Opening the self page using JavaScript open and then closing .. But nothing worked out ..

Comment: Yes. Can you show us? Can you create a demo that shows a bare-bones version of your page, and the popup, and the ok button that the user needs to click on... and your most recent attempted solution?

Comment: <input type=button onclick=self.close()>

Comment: This is wat I tried which is not working in Firefox alone

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var button = document.getElementById("...");
button.click = function() {
    window.close();
}
```

Where `...` is the ID of the button.

Comment: Does it work in Firefox ?!!

Comment: Yes, it works on all platforms.

Comment: @NishanthGandhidoss It won't work anywhere. DOM objects don't have `on`  method.

Comment: Please note that it should be `button.onclick = fn`.

Comment: I have tried something like this with jquery .. Its working ?? Can you please try out in Firefox ..

Comment: Can it be in a script tag itself .. Or something else have to be added to it ..

Comment: It can be added into the script tag.

Comment: @DripDrop the solution is not working in chrome as well as firefox